how to create a BSC safe contract on the 1.1.1 version when i
I've encountered an issue where I sent BNB to a Safe contract on Ethereum (v1.1.1) at a time when BSC was not yet supported on that version. Now, I'm struggling to recover the BNB from this address, even though I can see the balance on BSC Scan associated with the Ethereum Safe address contract.
Details of the Issue
Contract and Version: The BNB was sent to an Ethereum Safe contract on version 1.1.1, which did not support BSC at the time.
Steps Taken:
I attempted to replay the HEX data to create the identical Safe address on the BSC network, but this approach didn’t work.
I then tried using the new BSC proxy address available in the updated Safe version, but this also didn’t resolve the issue.
Current Status: On BSC Scan, I can see that my Ethereum Safe address contract reflects the BNB balance, but I am unable to interact with it to withdraw or transfer the funds.
Question
Is there a way to retrieve the BNB sent to this Ethereum Safe address, given the constraints of v1.1.1 and the addition of BSC support in later versions? Specifically:
Are there recommended methods to access or transfer the BNB in this situation, possibly through an alternative BSC proxy or Safe version?
Should I be attempting to recover access via a different HEX or contract replay approach?
Any advice on recovery methods, especially if specific to older Safe contract versions, would be appreciated.

have you gone through the official article - https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover
